# Python: Get multiple id's from checkbox

Tags: python, html, django

I wanted to get multiple id's from a list using checkbox. I got an error

> Field 'id' expected a number but got [].

Below is my code.

*sample.html*

```
<button href="/sample/save">Save</button>
{% for obj in queryset %}
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="sid" value="{{obj.id}}"></td>
    <td>{{ obj.sample_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.sample_type}}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.number}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

*views.py*

```
def sample(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = SampleList.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'lab_management/sample.html', {'queryset': queryset})


def save_doc(request):
    sid = request.POST.getlist('sid')
    sample = SampleList.objects.filter(id=sid)[0:10]
    template = DocxTemplate("doc.docx")

    context = {
        'headers' : ['Name', 'Type', 'Number'],
        'doc': [],
    }


    for samp in sample:
        list = [samp.name, samp.type, samp.number]         
        context['doc'].append(list)


    template.render(context)
    template.save('new_doc.docx')
```

Comment: Could you show more of the error?

Comment: Can you post the error, and the urls.py config for these views?

Comment: @nigel222 just one error, which it only got an empty list []. What about urls? Do I need to put the {{ obj.id }} there?

Comment: urls no longer needed. I was covering bases. Looks to me as if Sumit's answer is probably what you want. For future reference also post the part of the error traceback which includes lines of your code, with an indication of which line failed. `sample = SampleList.objects.filter(id=sid)[0:10]` if the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

the field id should be int you passed a list, that's why you got error:

> Field 'id' expected a number but got [].

Here you can use the [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) Filed lookup

Try this

```
sample = SampleList.objects.filter(id__in=sid)[0:10]
```

this will show all the `SampleList` items with the id's in `sid`

Update

Change your context to

```
context = {
    'headers' : ['Name', 'Type', 'Number'],
    'doc': sample,
}
```

then remove this for loop

```
#    for samp in sample:
#        list = [samp.name, samp.type, samp.number]         
#        context['doc'].append(list)
```

and in your  template

```
{% for obj in doc %}
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="sid" value="{{obj.id}}"></td>
    <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.type}}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.number}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

*NB: assuming name, type and number are the filed names of `SampleList` model*

Comment: no error occured, but I didn't get any id

Comment: check the updated answer, also add your models.